# Make square bracket not appear on a new line?

Tags: perl, sorting, debugging, text

I am currently working with a .txt file containing data points of certain files. 
Since the files are pretty big, are they been processed in smaller parts, but the output extracted from the processing process is not sorted in any order..

They are stored as such:

```
1_1_0_1_0_1_1_0_232  [
  0 -19.72058 -18.89882 ]
1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0  [
  -0.5940279 -1.949468 -1.185638 ]
1_0_1_1_0_1_1_1_100  [
  -5.645662 -0.005585805 -6.196068 ]
1_0_1_1_0_1_1_1_101  [
  -15.86037 -1.192093e-07 -18.77053 ]
1_0_1_1_0_1_1_1_102  [
  -0.5648238 -1.970869 -1.230303 ]
1_0_1_1_1_0_1_0_103  [
  -0.5750521 -1.946886 -1.222114 ]
1_0_1_1_1_0_1_0_104  [
  -0.5926428 -1.941596 -1.191844 ]
1_0_1_1_1_0_1_0_105  [
  -25.25665 0 -31.0921 ]
1_0_1_1_1_0_1_0_106  [
  -0.001282441 -6.852591 -8.399776 ]
1_0_1_1_1_0_1_0_107  [
  -0.0001649993 -8.857877 -10.69688 ]
1_0_1_1_1_0_1_0_108  [
  -21.66693 0 -26.18516 ]
1_0_1_1_1_0_1_0_109  [
  -5.444038 -0.004555213 -8.408965 ]
1_1_0_1_0_1_0_0_200  [
  -4.023561 -0.01851013 -7.704897 ]
1_1_0_1_0_1_0_0_201  [
  -0.443548 -3.057277 -1.167226 ]
1_1_0_1_0_1_0_0_202  [
  -0.0001185011 -9.042104 -15.60585 ]
1_1_0_1_0_1_0_0_203  [
  -5.960466e-07 -14.37778 -25.2224 ]
1_1_0_1_0_1_0_0_204  [
  -0.5770675 -1.951139 -1.21623 ]
1_1_0_0_1_0_1_1_205  [
  -0.5849463 -1.938798 -1.207353 ]
1_1_0_0_1_0_1_1_206  [
  -0.5785673 -1.949474 -1.214192 ]
1_1_0_0_1_0_1_1_207  [
  -27.21529 0 -32.21676 ]
1_1_0_0_1_0_1_1_208  [
  -8.75938 -0.0001605878 -12.53627 ]
1_1_0_0_1_0_1_1_209  [
  -1.281936 -0.3837854 -3.188763 ]
1_0_0_0_0_0_0_1_20  [
  -0.2104172 -4.638866 -1.714325 ]
1_1_1_0_0_1_1_1_310  [
  -11.71479 -9.298368e-06 -13.70222 ]
1_1_1_0_0_1_1_1_311  [
  -24.71166 0 -30.45412 ]
1_1_1_0_0_1_1_1_312  [
  -2.145031 -0.1357486 -4.617914 ]
1_1_1_0_0_1_1_1_313  [
  -5.943637 -0.003112446 -7.630904 ]
1_1_1_0_0_1_1_1_314  [
  0 -25.82314 -31.98673 ]
1_1_1_0_0_1_1_1_315  [
  -8.178092e-05 -13.60563 -9.426649 ]
1_1_1_0_0_1_1_1_316  [
  -0.00326875 -6.071715 -6.952539 ]
1_1_1_0_0_1_1_1_317  [
  -17.92782 0 -24.64391 ]
1_1_1_0_0_1_1_1_318  [
  -2.979753 -0.05447901 -6.11194 ]
1_1_1_0_0_1_1_1_319  [
  -0.7661145 -1.118131 -1.568804 ]
1_0_0_0_0_0_0_1_31  [
  -0.5749408 -1.961912 -1.215127 ]
1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_10  [
  -4.64927e-05 -9.977531 -20.60117 ]
1_0_1_1_1_1_0_1_120  [
  -0.4925551 -1.135103 -2.694917 ]
1_0_1_1_1_1_0_1_131  [
  -0.6127387 -1.958336 -1.148721 ]
1_1_0_0_0_0_0_1_142  [
  -0.008494892 -6.882521 -4.901772 ]
1_1_0_0_0_1_1_1_153  [
  0 -20.48085 -27.38916 ]
1_1_0_0_1_0_1_0_164  [
  -0.5370184 -1.622399 -1.52286 ]
1_1_0_0_1_0_1_0_175  [
  -24.08685 0 -29.42813 ]
1_1_0_0_1_1_1_0_186  [
  -1.665665 -0.2307523 -4.074597 ]
1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_1  [
  -0.5880737 -1.945877 -1.198183 ]
1_1_0_0_1_0_1_1_210  [
  -0.001396737 -6.574267 -21.30147 ]
1_1_0_1_0_1_1_0_221  [
  -0.7456465 -1.893918 -0.980585 ]
1_0_0_0_0_0_1_1_42  [
  -3.838613e-05 -10.23002 -13.01793 ]
1_0_0_0_0_0_1_1_43  [
  -22.25132 0 -28.8467 ]
1_0_0_0_0_0_1_1_44  [
  -6.688306 -0.001266626 -10.79875 ]
1_0_0_0_0_0_1_1_45  [
  -0.429086 -2.197691 -1.436171 ]
1_0_0_0_0_0_1_1_46  [
  -0.6683982 -1.928907 -1.072464 ]
1_0_0_0_1_0_0_1_47  [
  -0.5767454 -1.972311 -1.206838 ]
1_0_0_0_1_0_0_1_48  [
  -0.5789171 -1.965128 -1.206118 ]
1_0_0_0_1_0_0_1_49  [
  -19.90514 0 -25.12686 ]
1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_4  [
  -4.768373e-07 -14.66496 -28.4888 ]
1_0_0_0_1_0_0_1_50  [
  -0.01524216 -6.729354 -4.273614 ]
1_0_0_0_1_0_0_1_51  [
  -3.576279e-07 -14.9054 -27.44406 ]
1_0_0_0_1_0_0_1_53  [
  -0.003753785 -8.922103 -5.623135 ]
```

The format it is stored in is: `<name>_<part> [<data points>]`

I currently use a perl script to sort the datapoints.

```
perl -n00e '
    while ( /([\d_]*)_(\d*) \s* \[ \s* (.*?) \s* \]/gmsx ) {
        ($name,$part,$datapoints) = ($1,$2,$3);
        $hash{$name}{$part}=$datapoints;
    }
    while (($key,$v)=each %hash) {
        print "$key [\n", (
            map "${$v}{$_}\n", sort {$a<=>$b} keys %{$v}
        ), "]\n";
    }
'
```

Which creates an output as such:

```
0_0_1_1_0_1_1_1 [
-0.5757762 -1.949812 -1.219321
-0.5732827 -1.974719 -1.212248
-0.005632018 -5.198827 -9.280998
-0.004484621 -7.180546 -5.595852
-1.776234e-05 -10.93515 -20.11548
-22.73301 0 -29.42717
-4.227753 -0.01532919 -7.374347
-3.396693 -0.05122549 -4.10732
-0.0008418526 -7.08029 -20.86733
-21.26725 0 -27.1029
-2.457597 -0.09611109 -5.11661
-5.492554 -0.00666456 -5.981491
-12.60927 -3.576285e-06 -15.31444
-0.5809742 -1.953598 -1.2077
-0.5807223 -1.969571 -1.200681
]
...
```

Which is correct, but the end square bracket should not be on a new line, 
but be placed a space distance after the last data point has been printed. 
It doesn't look like the Perl script itself explicitly makes a new line
but some of the commands are invoking a new line.. is it possible to negate this effect?

Comment: The line in question is `map "${$v}{$_}\n", sort{ ... }keys %{$v}` . The '\n' adds a new line after every data point. After the last data point, a "]\n" is added. Instead, you can put all the datapoints in an array,  join() the array by newline, then print the closing bracket.

Comment: Makes sense... I guess i should have made the line that was in question a bit clearer... but thanks for making me aware of the join() function.. @bytepusher. I will give it a try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what @bytepusher recommended in comments:

```
while (($key,$v)=each %hash) {
        print "$key [\n", join("\n",
            map "${$v}{$_}", sort {$a<=>$b} keys %{$v}
        ), "             ]\n";
}
```